# ActiveRecord Query. Group by multiple columns from multiple tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

```
Attendance.joins(:user).group(:email, :name).count
```

The query above gives me the below results. "User 1" had 2 attendances and "User 2" had 6 attendance, plus I have access to the user name and email.

```
{["email@example.com", "User 1"]=>2, ["email2@example.com", "User 2"]=>6]}
```

This is great except I'd really like the User.id to be included as well. I can't group by the ID because then each record will be unique instead of being grouped by email and name. The below is what i'd like:

```
{[1, "email@example.com", "User 1"]=>2, [2, "email2@example.com", "User 2"]=>6]}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Answer**
    Attendance.joins(:user).group(:email, :name, 'attendances.user_id').count

Comment: It shouldn't be unique unless you group by `Attendence.id`?

Comment: Grouping by ID would be the ID of Attendence. Grouping by user_id, which I assume is on that table, would give you what you want.

Comment: How would you construct this query? I keep getting an error.... "Attendance.joins(:user).group(:email, :name, 'attendance.user_id').count" the error i get is "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "attendance""

Comment: The table name will be plural - try `attendances`

Comment: You guys were totally right! I swear i tried that a thousand times ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
Attendance.joins(:user).group(:email, :name, 'attendances.user_id').count
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# collect required fields and group by email, name
grouped_attendance = Attendance.joins(:user).pluck(:id, :email, :name).group_by{|r| [r[1], r[2]]}

# calculate the counts
attendance_counts = grouped_attendance.each{|k,v| grouped_attendance[k] = v.count}
```

Depending on your setup, but above should be fast enough as you are not instantiating ActiveRecord objects.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I get the following error when i tried that first query: undefined method `email' for [1, "email@examplecom", "User 1"]:Array

Comment: Corrected the syntax - r is an array (not an object) - will have to use array index for grouping